# Unable to connect to Verizon POP Email under DSL

Tags: networking, 12.04, email, thunderbird, evolution

Prior to this, I was using Verizon for my standard Telephone connection. I updated my Telephone line to use DSL last Month, and the DSL part is working perfectly.  For the past two weeks, I've been trying to get my new Email account to work that came from Verizon along with the upgrade to DSL, but I'm not having any success.
From Verizon and from the Internet, I got the following information:

```
                 Server             Port  Encryption    Data
     Incoming    pop.verizon.net    995      SSL        Normal Password
     Outgoing    smtp.verizon.net   465      SSL        Normal Password
```

Clients:

I've tested this in two Mail Clients, Evolution and Thunderbird.  Basically the same results:

```
Authentication Failure on password during POP processing
```

In Thunderbird:

Email name `MyUser@verizon.net`

When I select "Manual config", it gives the following:

```
                 Server  hostname  Port    SSL     Authentication
Incoming   POP3  pop.verizon.net   995   SSL/TLS   Normal password
Outgoing   SMTP  smtp.verizon.net  465   SSL/TLS   Normal password
Username   Input  MyUser                Output   MyUser
```

When I click "Re-Test" button, it runs fine, but when the "Done" button is pressed, I get the following message:

```
Configuration could not be verified - is the username or password wrong
```

It creates an account but when I attempt to process the messages from the Server at Verizon, it gets the following messages:

```
Sending of password for MyUser did not succeed
```

```
Mail Server pop.verizon.net responded: Authentication failed
```

Evolution:

It generates an Account successfully using the above values, but when I attempt to get any mail from my Verizon inbox, I get the following messages:

```
Unable to connect to POP server pop.verizon.net
```

```
Error sending password ERR [AUTH] authentication failed
```

Username and Passwords are correct since I use them on myverizon and webmail.

Environment:

- PC running Ubuntu - Precise Pangolin - All up to date

Firewall:

- Firewall is NOT active
- `sudo ufw status`

  ```
  Status: inactive
  ```

Modem/Router:

My Modem is a Verizon, Westell and has its Firewall set to:

```
No Security (None)
all Traffic is allowed
```

Comment: We do not accept support from personal e-mails. Ask Ubuntu is free for all but this also means anyone should be able to benefit from answers.

Comment: Is there anyone who has a similar Problem?

Comment: Getting same response from verizon "it is an issue with your email client." Same issue with windows & linux. Outlook/thunderbird/sylpheed.

Answer (score 0):

[verizon.net email moving to AOL Mail](https://www.verizon.com/support/consumer/email) in phases. So, it looks like there is something going on, on their end, and you just get to suffer through the problems.

In my case the aol system does not yet know about the userid/password so it looks like no is going to accept responsibility.